# Retrieve combobox value in javascript

Tags: javascript, combobox, selectedvalue

This is my little program, what could i do for take the combobox value??

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="NewFile.css">
  <title>Insert title here</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function calcola(){
        var op = String(document.getElementById("combo").value);
        alert(op);
    }   
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="in">
    Inserire il primo numero: 
    <input type="text" id="primo">
    <br>
    Inserire il secondo numero:
    <input type="text" id="secondo">
  </div>
  <div class="in">
    <select id="combo">
      <option selected="selected">*</option>
      <option>/</option>
      <option>+</option>
      <option>-</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="button" name="bottone" value="Premi" onclick="calcola();">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

This program should be a calculator, but I omitted most of code because it's necessary to know the operator befor doing calculations.

Comment: What is the problem? http://jsbin.com/oduqop/1

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
function calcola()
{
    var element = document.getElementById("combo");
    var op = element.options[element.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(op);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function:

```
function calcola(){
    var elt = document.getElementById("combo"),
        op = elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(op);
}
```

Buon lavoro collega italiano ;)

Comment: You beat me by 7 seconds :)

Comment: It is a matter of seconds :P

Comment: Yup it always is ;)The only difference being 'text' n 'value' :D

Comment: He has no value set for his options, so value in this case should return nothing(an empty string I think)

Comment: grazie mille! solo un chiarimento, se al posto di text avessi messo value?

Comment: Here, english is better! `<option value="/">/</option>` if you wanted to use `value` then you had to set it inside your `option` tag.